# Code runs fine in pycharm, but when converted to exe it does not

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller, webdriver-manager

Basically my code runs fine in Pycharm, but when I convert it to exe using Pyinstaller, it doesn't work and gives me error.

I've tried some changes but all attempts failed.

Selenium.py

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import ctypes
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
width = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) # 2560 mine for example
height = user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) # 1440 mine for example

wT = width / 3
hT = height / 2
wB = width / 2
answer = height / 36
hB = (height / 2) - answer

wPa = width / 3
wPa2 = wPa * 2

hPa = height / 2
wPa3 = width / 2


def Window1():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/")
    driver.set_window_size(wT, hT)
    driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window1()
```

Run.py

```py
import threading
import Selenium
import time

t1 = threading.Thread(target=Selenium.Window1)

t1.start()
time.sleep(2)
```

^that is a cut down version of my code, mine opens 5 windows instead of 1 but this is just for an example of what I'm doing/how I'm threading it. Hopefully this is enough.

This is the error i get when i try to run the exe:

[image]

Comment: What is the path of the binary driver for Firefox on your system?

Comment: Do you mean the geckodriver.exe or the firefox.exe path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that PyInstaller can't resolve `webdriver_manager`. So you just need to add whole library as a data file with [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-data-files):

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data ".\env\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager;webdriver_manager" script.py
```

Remember to replace the `webdriver_manager` path with a correct one.

Comment: I've had a look at adding a datafile and my brain has legit stopped working, for my example, where/how would i add this in?

Comment: Fixed it haha! just needed to sort my path and it worked. Thanks!